# Different of an element references

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory, local-field

In the book of  J. Neukirch  (Algebraic number theory) for global fields is defined the notion of different of an element.
It is possible also for local fields give such a definition?
Can you suggest some references?

Comment: From pp. 195-197 in my version of Neukirch's book, we are given a finite separable field extension $L/K$, so these can be local fields.

Comment: @Watson yeah but i was hoping in something more specific involving maybe valuations